# Autofill From Last Row of Old Data to New Data

Tags: excel, vba

I have a set of data that I am copying and pasting each month, but I need to fill in a column that starts at the "old" data to the new pasted data. So, I have two different sets of `LastRow` values, but I'm not sure how to indicate the range for it to fill.

```
 Dim RR As Long
 Dim LastRow3 as Long
 RR = Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 Range("C" & LastRow3, ":C" & RR).Value = "August"
```

Comment: Can you explain how you, the human, would identify the lastrow for the `LastRow3` variable? (End of the old data, I assume).

Comment: Can we assume that column C is empty for the new data?

Comment: @JNevill Yes, the end of the old data. I forgot to include it because it is actually defined above this section of the macro.

Comment: Yes @ScottCraner Column C is empty for the new data

Comment: `Range("C" & LastRow3 & ":C" & RR).Value = "August"`

Comment: Wow, I did a comma instead of & :/ Thanks though! @ScottCraner